Anylogic statechart exit action linkedto a resource pool
Im trying to remove a unit from a resource pool as an exit action on a state.
If I write:
 if (resourceUnitsOfPool(IK) = 1){IK.freeUnits(1);
}else {
    trace("No resources available in IK to remove.");
}

I get: Description: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable. Location: Model_test/trial/SK1 - State
Previous attempts with "hasUnits", "resourceUnitsAvailable", were undefined for the type ResourcePool. Additionally, if I use:
if (resourceUnitOfPool(IK) >= 0){IK.freeUnits(1);
} else {trace("No resources available in IK to remove.");
}

I get: Description: The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) Agent, int. Location: Model_test/trial/SK1 - State
Any clues? Thnxs

its enough to only use the tag "anylogic", btw. Welcome to SOF and AnyLogic :)


The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Your conditon uses = but should use ==. Ensure you understand the difference between assignment and comparison in Java.

Description: The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) Agent,

Now you use correct comparison but the call to resourceUnitOfPool(IK) does not return an integer number that can be compared, it returns an Agent object. So you try to compare an agent to a number, which is pointless.
Use a function that returns the number of free resources in a pool, for example idle() as an int
So the condition if (myResourcePool.idle() >= 0) will not throw errors
